# How to subscribe to multiple topics declaratively in Dapr Pub/Sub component?

Tags: dapr

Dapr already allows us to [subscribe multiple apps to a topic declaratively](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/pubsub/howto-publish-subscribe/#declarative-subscriptions).

But can we use just one `subscription.yaml` file to subscribe an app to multiple topics declaratively?

Something like:

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  name: myevent-subscription
spec:
- topic: newOrder
  route: /orders
  pubsubname: pubsub
- topic: newProduct
  route: /productCatalog/products
  pubsubname: pubsub
scopes:
- myapp
```

I know how to [subscribe an app to multiple topics **programmatically**](https://github.com/dapr/quickstarts/tree/master/pub-sub#node-message-subscriber), but "*the declarative approach removes the Dapr dependency from your code and allows, for example, existing applications to subscribe to topics, without having to change code*"[¹](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/pubsub/howto-publish-subscribe/#step-2-subscribe-to-topics) and it's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have multiple Subscription entries in a single file, certainly for Kubernetes deployments, like this.

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  name: orders-subscription
spec:
  topic: newOrder
  route: /orders
  pubsubname: pubsub
scopes:
- app1
- app2

---

apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  name: products-subscription
spec:
  topic: newProduct
  route: /productCatalog/products
  pubsubname: pubsub
scopes:
- app1
- app2
```

Comment: ok ok you got me, you have just one file. But it seems a little verbose, doesn't it? It would be nice if there was another way

Comment: This seems to give an error "two identical subscriptions found" when your pubsub name is the same, even if everything else is different. Example, I want to publish to one topic and subscribe to another using this approach.